# Rails Postgres database setup on Travis CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, travis-ci

EDIT, SOLVED:

It's working fine now. Code below has been updated.

Changes made:
I prepended 'bundle exec' to the 'rake:db migrate' command. 
I renamed database to 'travis'. When I had it as 'tavis_ci_test' it was still expecting 'travis' as the database name.

---

I'm trying to setup Travis CI for the first time with my Rails app using a Postgres database.

Error:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "travis" does not exist
```

database.yml

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: travis
```

.travis.yml

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.2.4

services:
  - postgresql

before_script:
  - "psql -c 'create database travis;' -U postgres"
  - "bundle exec rake db:migrate"
```

Thanks